# Error HamsterDB in Make

Tags: hamsterdb

I want install HamsterDB for lessfs,
i do ./configure and  was ok , but when i write command Make , show below errors,
can you help me,Please?
anyone work with lessfs and hamsterdb?

```
[root@localhost hamsterdb-2.1.9]# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9'
Making all in 3rdparty
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/src'
Making all in 2protoserde
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/include'
Making all in ham
Making all in samples
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/samples'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/samples'
Making all in tools
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/tools'
Making all in ham_bench
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/tools/ham_bench'
  CXXLD    ham_bench
generator_parser.o: In function `remove':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:620: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::remove(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:620: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::remove(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
hamsterdb.o: In function `remove':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:620: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::remove(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
main.o: In function `file_size':
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:571: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:571: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
main.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:179: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
main.o: In function `boost::thread::join()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:767: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
main.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:179: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
main.o: In function `boost::thread::join()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:767: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
***collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
***make[3]: *** [ham_bench] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/tools/ham_bench'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9/tools'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/rpms/hamsterdb-2.1.9'
make: *** [all] Error 2******
[root@localhost hamsterdb-2.1.9]#
```